# SSRS URL to export to Excel Automatically

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that is hosted on SharePoint.  Is it possible to have the report automatically export the results into Excel?  I tried the following url:

http://someServerName/_layouts/15/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/Reports/Balance%20Sheet.rdl&rp:DateRange=Last Month&rs:Format=EXCEL

but it just automacially populates the parameter and executes the report.  Wonder if it couldn't just automatically export it.

Also, does anyone know of a resource that shows t-sql code that will create a subscription for a report that is hosted on SharePoint?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use the RSViewerPage.aspx for a download link. We use the direct link to the reportserver from Sharepoint.

```
http://someServerName/ReportServer?/Reports/Balance%20Sheet&rp:DateRange=Last Month&rs:Format=EXCEL
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding.  Stack overflow newbie here.  Not sure where or how to close this question but just wanted to say thank you for your feedback.  NVM...as with most things.  I found it after adding a comment.